# How to use a type from React for props of my own component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

For my component I need to pass the `inputmode` from outside as `props`.
The valid values for `<input inputMode=<valid values>>` are defined in the React types (node_modules@types\react\index.d.ts) as

```
interface HTMLAttributes<T> extends AriaAttributes, DOMAttributes<T> {
    [..]
    // Living Standard
    /**
     * Hints at the type of data that might be entered by the user while editing the element or its contents
     * @see https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#input-modalities:-the-inputmode-attribute
     */
    inputMode?: 'none' | 'text' | 'tel' | 'url' | 'email' | 'numeric' | 'decimal' | 'search';
    [..]
}
```

Any way to reference this list of possible values in my `Props` interface without copying all the possible values, which might be outdated in the future?

```
interface Props {
  inputmode: <how to use the allowed values defined in the React types>;
}
```

Comment: @RameshReddy that gives me `Cannot access 'HTMLAttributes.inputMode' because 'HTMLAttributes' is a type, but not a namespace. Did you mean to retrieve the type of the property 'inputMode' in 'HTMLAttributes' with 'HTMLAttributes["inputMode"]'?` and with `inputmode?: HTMLAttributes['inputMode'];` I get `Generic type 'HTMLAttributes<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).  TS2314`. Not sure what to put as generic type for my <input>? (new to React)

Comment: That generic will depend on the HTML element you are using such as `HTMLAttributes<HTMLTextAreaElement>['inputMode']`

Comment: @stefan.at.wpf As you can see in the interface `HTMLAttributes` is expecting a type arg`T`, so as mark said you can use `HTMLAttributes<HTMLTextAreaElement['inputMode']` or `HTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>['inputMode']`.

Comment: Mark, Ramesh, thank you both. It worked. But why can't one use the dot notation `HTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>.inputMode` ?

Comment: Typescript types don't use dot notation except for accessing members of a namespace.  You have to use brackets to get the properties of an object.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a type  like this.

```
interface Props {
    inputmode: HTMLAttributes['inputMode'];
}
```